# please could solve br tag in html it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

Could somebody explain to me, please, how I might solve this issue?

I tried to add a `<br>` after the `<small>` tag, to put the text-box after the label of `<small>` element, but it doesn't work.

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <small style="text-align: left;">Customize this Card as Your Name</small><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="MyName" name="MyName" placeholder="Your Own Signature" maxlength="40">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <small>Choose a Card</small><br>
        <select class="form-control input-lg" onchange="showImage(this.value)">
          <option value="1">Model 1</option>
          <option value="2">Model 2</option>
          <option value="3">Model 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button id="btnPreview" name="btnPreview" onclick="reviewImage()" class="btn-success btn-lg btn-custom">Preview <div class="icons"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" style="float:right"></i></div></button>
        <button type="button" id="btnDownload" name="btnDownload" class="btn-primary btn-lg btn-custom" onclick="downloadImage()">Download<div class="icons"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true" style="float:right"></i></div></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img id="imgCard" src="cards/1.png" alt="Eid Card" class="img-responsive responsiv_imageEn" />
    <canvas id="canvas" width="100%"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

---

this is my css code

`````
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'GE Dinar One Medium';
    src: url('../fonts/ge_dinar_one_medium.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/ge_dinar_one_medium.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/ge_dinar_one_medium.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/ge_dinar_one_medium.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ge dinarone bold';
    src: url('../fonts/ge dinarone bold.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/ge dinarone bold.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/ge dinarone bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/ge dinarone bold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'GE SS Two Bold';
    src: url('../fonts/GE SS Two Bold.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/GE SS Two Bold.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/GE SS Two Bold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/GE SS Two Bold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'GE Dinar Two Medium';
    src: url('../fonts/GE Dinar Two Medium_0.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/GE Dinar Two Medium_0.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/GE Dinar Two Medium_0.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/GE Dinar Two Medium_0.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


/* English fonts */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Neue Helvetica LTW20 Bold';
    src: url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLT\ W20\ 75\ Bold.otf');
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLT\ W20\ 75\ Bold.otf') format('.otf'), url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLT\ W20\ 75\ Bold.otf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLT\ W20\ 75\ Bold.otf') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTProCn';
    src: url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTProCn.otf');
    src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLTProCn.otf') format('.otf'), url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLT\ W20\ 75\ Bold.otf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/HelveticaNeueLT\ W20\ 75\ Bold.otf') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

* {
    text-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #F3F3F3 url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url(../images/bg.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    font: 13px 'GE Dinar One Regular';
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

img,
iframe {
    border: none
}

.w960 {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

#flat_form h2 {
    background: #006553;
    line-height: 1.9;
}

#flat_formEn h2 {
    background: #006553;
    line-height: 1.9;
}

#lanEn {
    float: left;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: black;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

#lanEn:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: #E8E8E8;
}

#lanAr {
    float: right;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: black;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

#lanAr:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: #E8E8E8;
}


/* =================================================================== */


/***Start Header***/

.blue_head {
    /*width: 100%; height:146px;  margin: 0 auto; background:#205578 url('../images/bg1_2.png') -85px -12px;*/
}

.headeritems {}

.header {
    z-index: 7;
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
}

.logo {
    float: right;
    background: url(/Card/Content/images/logo.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url(/Card/Content/images/logo.png);
    display: block;
    height: 79px;
    width: 206px;
    margin: 40px 20px 0 0;
}


/***Footer Section***/

.footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.footer>.footerGreen {
    background-color: #006553;
    color: #f3f3f3;
    font: 12px 'GE Dinar One Light';
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 11px 0 15px 0;
    line-height: 18px;
    width: 960px;
    border-bottom: solid 6px #C1AF64;
}

.footer>.footerGreen>.right {
    float: right
}

.footer>.footerGreen>.right>.rights {}

.footer>.footerGreen>.left {
    float: left
}

.footer>.footerGreen>.left>ul {
    margin: 6px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none
}

.footer>.footerGreen>.left>ul>li {
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
    text-align: center
}

.footer>.footerGreen>.left>ul>li>a {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 22px;
    display: inline-block
}

.footer>.footerGreen>.left>ul>li>a.w3c {
    background-image: url(../images/w3c.png);
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url(../images/w3c.svg);
    width: 48px
}

.footer>.footerBrowsers>.right {
    /* background: url('../images/browsers.png') no-repeat right 0px; */
    float: right;
    width: 545px;
    height: 43px;
    font: 11px 'GE Dinar One Light';
    padding: 10px 139px 0 0;
    line-height: 17px;
    color: #B0B0B0;
    margin-right: 15%;
}

.backtotop {
    background: url('../images/gototop.png') no-repeat;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url(../images/gototop.svg);
    width: 51px;
    height: 51px;
    position: fixed;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    bottom: 135px;
    left: 50px;
    display: none;
}

a {
    color: #16a085;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: .25s;
    transition: .25s;
}

h2,
.h2 {
    font-size: 53px;
}

small,
.small {
    font-size: 83%;
    line-height: 2.067;
}

ul,
ol {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007c5a;
}

.btn-success {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.btn-lg,
.btn-group-lg>.btn {
    padding: 10px 19px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.471;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.form-control::-moz-placeholder,
.select2-search input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #b2bcc5;
    opacity: 1;
}

.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder,
.select2-search input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #b2bcc5;
}

.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder,
.select2-search input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #b2bcc5;
}

.form-control,
.select2-search input[type="text"] {
    /*height: 42px;*/
    padding: 8px 12px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.467;
    color: #34495e;
    border: 2px solid #bdc3c7;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
    transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
}

.input-lg,
.form-group-lg .form-control,
.form-group-lg .select2-search input[type="text"] {
    height: 45px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.235;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

select.input-lg,
select.form-group-lg .form-control,
select.form-group-lg .select2-search input[type="text"] {
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
}

.form-group {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn-custom {
    width: 30% !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    margin: 5px;
}

.responsiv_image {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 25%;
}

.responsiv_imageEn {
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.form-control,
.select2-search input[type="text"] {
    /*height: 42px;*/
    padding: 8px 12px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.467;
    color: #34495e;
    border: 2px solid #bdc3c7;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
    transition: border .25s linear, color .25s linear, background-color .25s linear;
}

#flat_form {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    /* Fix for webkit rendering */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

#flat_formEn {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    /* Fix for webkit rendering */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: show;
}

#flat_form h2 {
    text-align: right;
    font-family: 'GE SS Two Bold';
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 26px;
    padding-left: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#flat_formEn h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Neue Helvetica LTW20 Bold';
    font-weight: 400;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 26px;
    padding-left: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#flat_form fieldset {
    background: #E8E8E8;
    font-family: 'GE Dinar One Medium';
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-right: 26px;
    padding-left: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}

#flat_formEn fieldset {
    background: #E8E8E8;
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLTProCn';
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    padding-top: 14px;
    padding-right: 26px;
    padding-left: 26px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
}

.icons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .header {
        margin: 0
    }
    .headeritems {
        min-height: 183px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .logo {
        margin: 34px auto 0;
    }
    .footer>.footerGreen {
        padding: 8px
    }
    .footer>.footerGreen>.right {
        float: none;
        font-size: 11px
    }
    .footer>.footerGreen>.right>.rights,
    .footer>.footerGreen>.right>.fLinks {
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 5px
    }
    .footer>.footerGreen>.left {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 5px
    }
    .footer>.footerGreen>.left>ul {
        display: inline-block
    }
    .footer>.footerBrowsers>.right {
        width: 70%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        background-position: center top;
        padding: 63px 0 0 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 15%;
        min-width: initial;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 626px) {
    .logo {
        margin: 34px auto 0;
        float: right;
        background-size: contain;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #flat_form input {
        /* border-radius: 3px; */
        /* border: 2px solid #fff; */
        /* text-align: right; */
        /* font-family: 'GE Dinar One Medium'; */
        /* font-size: 15px; */
        /* margin-right: 2%; */
        /* margin-bottom: 14px; */
        /* margin-top: 10px; */
        /* background: #fff; */
        /* color: #777; */
        /* padding: 4px 10px; */
        /* width: 40%; */
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .responsiv_image {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    #flat_form fieldset {
        background: #E8E8E8;
        font-family: 'GE Dinar One Medium';
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 16px;
        border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
        padding-top: 14px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-left: 26px;
        padding-bottom: 14px;
    }
    .btn-custom {
        width: auto !important;
        text-align: center !important;
        margin: 5px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .header {
        margin: 0 0 30px 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        /*height: auto;*/
    }
    .backtotop {
        left: 15px;
        bottom: 15px;
    }
    body {
        background-size: cover;
        /* background-attachment: fixed; */
    }
    .w960 {
        width: 96%;
        margin: 0 2%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .headeritems {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        min-height: 196px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    .footer {
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
    .footer>.footerGreen {
        width: 100%
    }
    .footer>.footerBrowsers>.right {
        min-width: 400px;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 53px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-position: right center;
    }
} ````
`````

Comment: Where? there's no <br> in your code nor any clear description where you intend to have a new line. A (minimal code) working snippet illustrating the problem would help here.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding `<br>` tag . you can use `css` to solve this problem .

```
small{
   display: block;
}
```

```css
small{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <small style="text-align: left;">Customize this Card as Your Name</small>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="MyName" name="MyName" placeholder="Your Own Signature" maxlength="40">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <small>Choose a Card</small>
        <select class="form-control input-lg" onchange="showImage(this.value)">
          <option value="1">Model 1</option>
          <option value="2">Model 2</option>
          <option value="3">Model 3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button id="btnPreview" name="btnPreview" onclick="reviewImage()" class="btn-success btn-lg btn-custom">Preview <div class="icons"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" style="float:right"></i></div></button>
        <button type="button" id="btnDownload" name="btnDownload" class="btn-primary btn-lg btn-custom" onclick="downloadImage()">Download<div class="icons"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true" style="float:right"></i></div></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img id="imgCard" src="cards/1.png" alt="Eid Card" class="img-responsive responsiv_imageEn" />
    <canvas id="canvas" width="100%"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: please check my css code, your sl not work with me. Thanks

Comment: copy `small{ display: block; }` and paste into `css` codes.